# We can have api to check valid/invalid session( cookie) or not in WSO2 IS?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

After login successfully in WSO2 IS. the system will return a cookie (session)  and I don't know We can have api to check valid/invalid session( cookie) or not  in WSO2 IS?

Comment: Please explain your usecase.

Comment: as I mentioned above. I want to check cookie or session is existing or not existing in the system of IS to inform for our user.

Answer (score 0):

As of now (IS 5.1.0), there is no API in the IS side to validate a cookie. But, there are set of session related configurations you can do in the client side such as configuring remember me period, clean up tasks, caching which might be useful to meet your requirement.

If you are using IS 5.0.0 + SP1 refer [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Enabling+Authentication+Session+Persistence) for more information.
If you are using IS 5.1.0 refer [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Enabling+Authentication+Session+Persistence).